# Django el-pagination adding URL parameters

Tags: django, django-endless-pagination

I have went trough the official documentation and i couldn't figure out how can i override/add additional user arguments to my GET request for additional filtering for like something like search. My current initialization looks like:

```
$('.infinite_scroll').endlessPaginate({paginateOnScroll: false});
```

Comment: You mean URL parameters?

Comment: Yes. I can add them on the initial ajax call. But when i scroll down, the default function doesn't have them so the query is messed up.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the url generated by `show_more` tag using javascript